# Unable to add connector update from Mulesoft exchange

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am using AnypointStudio 3.7 and trying to install object-store plugin from exchange. but when I click on install button I got an error displaying the message

"There was a problem loading the update site located at 
http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0"

The same error also occurs in order to install other plugins/connector like box from same repository.
I have tried to add the plugin from Help->Install New software window but there also getting the same error.

error getting here is :
"Unable to read repository at http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0/content.xml."

However I am able to install the updates from other sites like Anypoint update, DevKit etc but not able to install updates from connector update site.

Please anyone help me to find the reason why Anypoint is behaving like this:

FYI , I am using proxy setting in my machine. Could it be the cause of failure?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding from exchange, you can also try an option to add new software from Help -> Install New Software -> work with "Anypoint connector update site" -> specify "objectstore" in search. Select the appropriate ve

Answer (score 0):

@Md. Sadique Ansari  ... Please check http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0/content.xml this url from your browser first because this error mostly due to network firewall setting.
Are you assessing this in your organization network ??

Comment: Hi @Ranveer, I checked and URL is accessible from browser but problem is still with studio , anypoint is unable to read the directory...... yep it is accessible from organization network.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the message about this in the error logs...googling lead me here...

I noticed, in my attempts to manually test the urtl in a browser that some paths got flipped to HTTPS...so I changed the url in preferences to use HTTPS...and now no errors in the log!

(No updates either but...)